# What is the concept when creating an automatic send of email app on php

Tags: php, automation

I have an website running, and what I want to do is create a Table that has listed all the email that need to be sent, with all the information in it. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Send_Email
ID INT,
To VARCHAR(130),
Subject VARCHAR(130),
Message TEXT
```

What I want to do - and don't know how - is to check automatically if there is any record on this table, if there is: Send the email(s) and delete the row(s).

What I don't know is  what is the concept when building something like this. Where to put it? How to check it automatically? Do I put the loop code on my main "master controller" and run it every time someone loads up one of my pages? This looks like it will affect performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the ideal task for a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job (or any equivalent system).
You need a service running on your server, which will periodically perform your wanted action.
If you have your own server, this can be done for sure, but if you have your site hosted somewhere you need to check with the provider for this possibility.

**EDIT**: If you can't use scheduled jobs, it might still be reasonable to perform the action somewhere else. For example, if the records in the table are inserted only from within your website, you could configure it to forward an email as soon as it is sent by the writer, avoiding the need to regularly check the database (in fact, you wouldn't need a table at all). It is obvious though that this solution is not as flexible as the other one, and that it is applicable only in particular situations.

Comment: I am familiar with the service based method. I don't know if you are familiar with this, but researching the Magento framework I saw that it sends "newsletter" periodically and automatically, being even possible to set a particular date for it to send it. I don't think it uses a service on the server, because the installation is only via php.

Comment: I never used Magento, but from a quick research it seems that while Magento has a fully configurable newsletter, you also need a proper configuration of cron to get it working. Just have a look at the Magento forums and do a quick search on Google, you will be convinced.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you have a PHP script which performs an action, you need to execute that script to have that action performed (obviously). So, in the case of a website, the way to execute it would be one of the following: some random visitor, you (the administrator, launching the script manually), or a scheduler of some sort (like cron). There is absolutely no way for a script (which is a text file after all) to literally launch itself without any external help.